# How to get value corresponding to max aggregation function in mongodb using spring data

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data

I have following schema for my domain object

```
private String pair;
private String lProvider;
private double value;
private DateTime dateTime;
```

Following way i am creating object for this

```
 new TestMData("EUR", "ABC", 2.5454, DateTime.now().minusYears(3));
```

I wan to use spring data aggregation to find dateandtime corresponding to max value using spring aggravation.

One way is that i get the max value using aggregation and the find that value using findone method but i don't think it's good approach . Does Spring data provide feature where i can field corresponding to max value

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the dateandtime corresponding to max value with aggregation, you would need in your aggregation a sort step that is piped to the group operator where within the grouping you'd use the **[`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/#grp._S_first)** operator to get the top document when they are ordered:

```
db.collection.aggregate([ 
    { "$sort": { "value": -1 } },
    {
        "$group": {
            "_id": null,
            "largestValue": { "$first": "$value" },
            "date": { "$first": "$dateTime" }
        }
    }
])
```

**In Spring Data:**

```
import static org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.Aggregation.*;

Aggregation agg = newAggregation(
    sort(DESC, "value"),
    group().first("value").as("largestValue")
           .first("dateTime").as("date")     
);

AggregationResults<TestMData> results = mongoTemplate.aggregate(agg, "test", TestMData.class);
List<TestMData> testData = results.getMappedResults();
```

The above should have the same performance with **[`find()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.find/#db.collection.find)**, [**`sort()`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.sort/) and **[`limit()`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.limit/#cursor.limit)** combination:

```
db.collection.find().sort( { "value": -1 } ).limit(1)
```

Comment: Thanks for answer but i was looking if i can do without sort because i am already sorting on the basis of dateandtime .